# VB writeline writes corrupt lines to text file

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible for the following code to produce NUL values within a text file?

```
var temp_str = "123456;1234567"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path & "stats.txt", temp_str, False)
```

It seems simple, but it writes quite often and I'm seeing several files that get accessed by the application that have Strings written to as:
[image: file contents]

When opening the file with Notepad++. Some other editors show just squares, and it seems like each character is represented by a block/NUL.
So far I've been unable to reproduce this on my test system. I just find the files on a COMX module's file system that's been running in the field and comes back faulty, but I've been seeing enough of these files to make it a problem that needs to be solved.

Does anyone have an idea to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Likely cause is the encoding is different.  Take a look at the 4th param of My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText() where you can specify the encoding

Comment: @Hursey I doubt that the encoding changed. If not specified explicitly, VB Assumes UTF-8, if I'm not mistaken.  An example though, is the closing logs which write a log each time the application or device is being restarted.
`2020-06-17 14:01:31; The Software is Closing ... 
NULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNUL
2020-06-17 14:36:31; The Software is Closing ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what the problem is without more code, but try this if you want to replace the existing contents of the file:

```
Dim fileContent = "My UTF-8 file contents"
Using writer As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText(fullPathIncludingExtension)
    writer.Write(fileContent)
End Using
```

Or this if you want to append UTF-8 text:

```
Dim newLines = "My UTF-8 content to append"
Using writer As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPathIncludingExtension)
    writer.Write(fileContent)
End Using
```

If you want to append Unicode text, you must use a different constructor for StreamWriter:

```
Using writer As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("full/path/to/file.txt", True, Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    writer.Write(MyContentToAppend)
End Using
```

Note that the `True` argument to the constructor specifies that you want to append text.

Comment: Would you say using a streamwriter rather than the FileSystem.WriteAllText is a safer method of implementing it? The project I have inherited unfortunately has massive amounts of code, but I see this behavior both in a simple variable persisting file, as well as a logger, which also uses the WriteAllText method to append.

Comment: The only benefit I know of when using a StreamWriter rather than FileSystem methods is that you explicitly close the writer (using .Dispose() or the Using statement) when you're done writing. If you're writing in a loop, using FileSystem.WriteAllText will open the file, write, then close it repeatedly, rather than open it, write in a loop, and then close it. This gives better performance. I never use FileSystem.WriteAllText, so I suggested StreamWriter because I know how to specify the encoding, which I suspected was the issue.

Comment: Adding the Text encoding as also advsed by @Hursey in the comments seem to have resolved this issue. I have also managed to make the code concerned quite a bit more efficient for the looped writers. Thanks for the advice.